# Can i put Bitcoin Bitcore on Flashdrive?

Tags: wallet

I am a new user, Downloaded bitcore wallet and blockchain. I have received several bits of information of how much of a risk it is to leave your wallet live on the pc. I read about creating a cold storage so I bought a 32gb flash drive. my question is how to correctly move it to the drive,and will it operate normally when I put it back in my pc 2 weeks later?  I am useing windows if there is a detailed page or inscrutable please let me know thanks.

Comment: By bitcore, do you mean Bitcoin Core, or Bitpay Bitcore?

Comment: User has not returned to reply to questions asking for clarification, so I've voted to close as "unclear".